# Error of parameter of anonymus function - is not a type

Tags: go

could somebody clarify to me, please why golang complains on the code - "job is not a type"  in goroutine

```
type job func(in, out chan interface{})

func Execute(jobs ...job) {
    in := make(chan interface{}, 100)
    out := make(chan interface{}, 100)

    wg := &sync.WaitGroup{}
    for _, job := range jobs {
        wg.Add(1)
        go func(j job, waiter *sync.WaitGroup, in, out chan interface{}) {
            defer waiter.Done()
            defer close(out)
            j(in, out)
        }(job, wg, in, out)
        in = out
        out = make(chan interface{}, 100)
    }

    wg.Wait()
}
```

If I create separate function, or carry goroutine out of loops - all compiles fine

Comment: Sorry, it is my fault - type job is hided by name of variable in loop!

Answer (score 0):

It is because of this for-loop:

```
for _, job := range jobs {
   // In here, job is the loop variable
}
```

The loop variable `job` is shadowing the type name `job`. If you rename the loop variable to something else, it should work.

Answer (score -1):

```
type job func(in, out chan interface{})

.
.
.
    for _, jb := range jobs {
        .
        .
        .
        }(jb, wg, in, out)
```

Comment: Could you please add some explanation to the source code